# How can I fix screen tearing and flickering issues with KDE Plasma and SDDM after switching from GNOME on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, intel-graphics, macbook-air, sddm

I’m using a 2012 MacBook Air with an Intel i7-3667U processor and no dedicated GPU. I just reconfigured SDDM and went to use KDE, but I noticed that SDDM flickered white rapidly whenever at the login screen, KDE’s dock (weirdly just the dock) would flicker colors from my wallpaper, and there is also screen tearing whenever scrolling or moving around windows.

It’s worth noting that in the past, I did use KDE on this installation, but then switched over to GNOME for a time. At one point I uninstalled and reinstalled `kubuntu-desktop`, but I only began finding this problem after simply switching to gnome without uninstalling anything, and then switching back to KDE, my only prep for this being `sudo dpkg-reconfigure sddm`. It’s also worth noting that this likely isn’t an X11 issue, since running GNOME a with X11 exhibits none of the behavior mentioned in the title.

So, why could this be happening? Should I have run other commands before switching over? And how can I fix it?

Comment: Your issue reminds me of issues with an old *i386* box using the 19.10 (5.3 kernel) and Nvidia card... As that *architecture* had officially been *dropped* (but not disabled at that point) I ignored it.. but experienced it later on a far more modern box with another nVidia card.. The workaround  was just switching `sddm` to something else which maybe talked about [here](https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/login-screen-flashes/1634) as Lubuntu uses `sddm` too by default.  It may or may not be related to your issue; just your description reminded me of it.

Comment: I did try switching to GDM, and while its login screen did not exhibit flickering, KDE Plasma still had the aforementioned problems.